# Make Mailchimp Pop Up Redirect To A Page

Tags: javascript, css, mailchimp

When using MailChimp pop up I can not redirect people who just opted-in to another page, I can do that easily with Embedded form, but I'm wondering how to do it with that code

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js"
            data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { 
            L.start({
                "baseUrl":"mc.us18.list-manage.com",
                "uuid":"218acfebac44df61c3f27402c",
                "lid":"08af3cd08b"
            })
        })
    </script>
```